# What does ^BOOT coomand means on Huawei E220?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, gsm, at-command

I have connected Huawei USB UMTS modem (E220) to my Linux box, i.e. RaspberryPi.
Now I get 2 ttyUSB port available to communicate to it, where I use ttyUSB0 to establish mobile Internet connection and ttyUSB1 for other tasks, like sending and receiving SMSes, checking status and error codes, make modem configurations, etc.
At regular intervals (2secs) I get this AT command on port ttyUSB1:

```
^DSFLOWRPT:n,n,n,n,n,n,n
```

which I fully understand (link: [thanks to the user user **ginggs** from http://mybroadband.co.za](http://mybroadband.co.za/vb/showthread.php/21726-Linux-HOWTO-%28With-Stats%29/page37?p=715513#post715513)). Less frequently I also get **^BOOT** command, looking like this:

```
^BOOT:12659389,0,0,0,58
```

Can someone explain what those numbers in ^BOOT mean? Can I make notifications/warnings in ^DSFLOWRPT and ^BOOT be less/more verbose (something like "errors on/off")?

[edit]

Added link for understanding the ^DSFLOWRPT command.

Answer (score 5):

In AT Command Interface Specification, Huawei mention that ^BOOT unsolicited command only for the Huawei specified client, nothing specific.

You can disable all unsolicited result by the following AT command:

```
AT^CURC=0
```

To enable it back just change 0 to 1:

```
AT^CURC=1
```